# How to prevent gitk from removing part of branch name before slash?

Tags: git, gitk

When I am using `gitk` GUI and I checkout to (create) remote-tracking branch (right-click and checkout) (`origin/type/branch`), branch named `branch` is created - not `type/branch`. Is there possibility how to preserve also the part before the last slash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the moment there is no way to make gitk preserve anything before the last `/` when creating a local branch from a remote tracking branch.

You need to use the CLI, or you may want to consider some other graphical tools, i.e. [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/).